# Recursion in is power function in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing my course exercise that states the following:

A number `a` is a power of `b` if:

1. it is divisible by `b`
2. `a/b` is a power of `b`.

Write a function called `is_power` that takes parameters `a` and `b` and returns `True` if `a` is a power of `b`.

However, I have to do it using recursion and somehow using the following function:

```
def is_divisible(x, y):
    if x % y == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I don't know exactly where they relate to each other but yeah, that's what I'm supposed to do.

What I did so far (without using the above function) is:

```
def is_power(a, b):
    while a % b == 0:
        if a == b: return True
        a = a / b
    return False
```

print(10, 2)

Thoughts on why I have no output/how to relate the `is_divisible` function to `is_power`?

Comment: check your indentation for print and within function `def is_power`

Comment: there are comment elements `if x % y == 0:` and `while a % b == 0:` could probably replace one with the other using function call

Answer (score 3):

If `a` is a power of `b`, then `a` is divisible by `b`. Logically the contrapositive is also true i.e. if `a` is not divisible by `b`, then `a` is not a power of `b`. This is where your `is_divisible` function possibly comes in - to break out of the recursion, not to propagate it.

In case `is_divisible(a, b)` returns `True`, then you go to your second condition, `a/b` is a power of `b`. Do we have a function that when given two numbers checks if one of them is a power of the other? This is the condition to propagate the recursion.

Think about what your base case will be if `a` does happen to be a power of `b`.